# Call a php function in another php file?

Tags: php, function, variables

I need to call a function from index.php in another file example.php. If I use include it also takes all the html from index.php. I just want the result of the function. Any way to do this?

```
                        $rs = odbc_exec($con, $sql);
                        if (!$rs) {
                            exit("There is an error in the SQL!");
                        }
                        $data[0] = array('D','CPU_Purchased_ghz');
                        $i = 1;


                        while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) {
                        $data[$i] = array(
                            $row['D'],
                            $row['CPU_Purchased_ghz']
                        );
                        $i++; 
                        }


                    //odbc_close($con); // Closes the connection
                    $json = json_encode($data); // Generates the JSON, saves it in a variable
                    echo $json;
```

Basically that piece of code in index.php takes info from a file which queries a db and encodes it in json. Instead of echoing I wanted to make a function that echos the json and call it in a new file to only get the json displayed on the page

Comment: Can we have the said-function?

Comment: You have to refactor the code. There is no other way.

Comment: What about writing the function to a third file (`function.php`) and including this file in `index.php` and `example.php`?

Comment: I don't think I can because it's the result of querying a db from information provided in a html form, I just thought it'd be easy to put the result in a function and then get it in another file

Answer (score 0):

create a `functions.php` file. Add the function to that file and include the file in your `example.php` file

Comment: I can't because it's the result of querying a db from information provided in a html form

Comment: yeah sorry I'll include it now

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
function myFunction() {
    return "It works!";
}
```

example.php

```
include('index.php');
echo myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the file before you call the function.

**See below examples:**

**index.php**

```
<?php
function myFunction() { //function .
    return "FirstProgram"; //returns
}
?>
```

Now Using include http://php.net/include to include the index.php to make its content available for use in the second file:

**example.php**

```
<?php
    include('index.php');
    echo myFunction();  //returns myFunction();
?>
```

Comment: @Vickie follow this example and do it your task first and if any errors please let me know.

Comment: Hey as I said in the question, using Include also returns the html form in the new file which I don't want, I just want the json php output!

Comment: what is there in html,you can write html in another program and only call the index file in example program.

Comment: The html is the form that takes in the data so I think I need them in the same file - see edited question :)

Comment: please mention both files we can easily understand your question.

Comment: I meant to say takes input from a form not file, so from a form in index.php

Comment: I mean to say you can mention both index.php and example.php files in your question ,we can easily understand your question.

Comment: example.php would just be calling the function so jsonFunction(); or whatever, I don't think it's possible to do anyway in php , thanks for your help anyway